# Laravel Passport and SSL on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, laravel-passport

I recently purchase a SSL and install on heroku. when i try the laravel passport api on postman it says:

> Error: Unable to verify the first certificate

when the link is https://www.example.com/login
but when i change the link to http://www.example.com/login it is working just fine.
i also add this code block on AppServiceProvider

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

to force the site to https.

Is there a way to work the passport on HTTPS links?